# SASS REM in best practices

Tags: css, sass

I would like to make a mobile first website that use rem units, but some question i can not solve.

This is my setting:

```
EM media queries
```

and

```
html {
  font-size: 14px; // base font size
}

@media (min-width: 62em) { // i need all of the element scale when min-width is 62em
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.element {
  border-width: 0.0625rem; // 1px border
  padding: .5rem 1rem; // rem padding
}
```

My question is

1. when zoom in to > 110%, the 62em media queries change, and html font size back to base 14px, any method to solve it?
2. when zoom out, 0.0625rem border is disappear, because its < 1px, so if any style is 1px, then should not use rem on it? how about 1.5px or 2px?
3. i read some of article that suggest about do not change html font size, just leave it 100%, if i follow this method and need to get same result of above example, i need use sass mixin to calc all of the css style with 14px base font size and 16px base font size in different media queries?